# How to import contacts from various mail providers (gmail,yahoo, hotmail) using .net

Tags: .net

I want to import the contacts from different mail providers like gmail, yahoo and hotmail in .net. The goal is to retrieve a list of contact to send an email to each of them.
What apis exist to retrieve these informations? Is there an unified api to query all these providers?

Answer (score 0):

To access contacts information on

GMail -  Google data APIs: https://developers.google.com/gdata/client-cs

Hotmail - Live Connect Developer Center: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/live/default.aspx

Yahoo - Yahoo! Contacts API: http://developer.yahoo.com/social/contacts/. In my experience is YQL is the best solution to get Yahoo info.